# tool analyzing log4net logs

Tags: logging, statistics, log4net

Is there a tool which can be used to analyze log4net logs.

Particulary I would like to extract two method calls by thread id and analyze the duration between the two, to create some statistics of call duration.

Plus this over multiple (100x10Mb) files.

I suppose *grep* would also do it.

Answer (score 5):

Well this may or may not be a bad answer, but when you use log4j, there's a tool called Chainsaw (written in Java) that you can use to filter and go through your log4j-like log files.

Note: You may need to refer to this article to configure chainsaw to read your log file file:

http://wiki.apache.org/logging-log4j/Configuring_a_log4j_RollingFileAppender_with_Chainsaw

Comment: I gave it a shot, but it seems like it doesn't work with log4net logs.

Comment: Really?  Look at the format of the logs.  And make sure it matches what you have being output from it.

Comment: It might also have something to do with which version of chainsaw you compiled.  As I remember I had to go to the repository to compile it, rather than just getting the binary jars for it.

Comment: It's not easy to do this...maybe I will have to drop it on drop.io for you over lunch.

Comment: (I have it compiled at home, I think...)

Comment: You could also give baretail a try: http://www.baremetalsoft.com/baretail/ It's not quite as good, but it will help.

Comment: Here's something that might help even more...
http://geekswithblogs.net/kobush/archive/2005/07/15/46627.aspx

Comment: P.S. I've uploaded that compiled binary version I spoke of,to http://drop.io/fapocx0

It may help...I hope so...

Let me know if any of this has helped.

Comment: Sorry have not seen your comments, in the mean time I have done it with GREP and SORT plus some other tools (as I needed it very fast), neverthe less thanks for your effort.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the XML log formatting. You can process the log files. using xpath to extract the details you want. But you would have a write a small app yourself.

Answer (score 0):

In case you use the XML Log you could write a XSL Stylesheet and reference it from the XML.
Then you just need to point your browser to the XML and it will style the XML with your XSL Stylesheet for you to see the data as HTML (or whatever, XSL is very powerful).

Comment: It is a plain TXT log, plus there are at least 20x10Mb files.